# Swift functions with no parameters

Tags: swift

I have some simple code in my Utilities.swift because I can never remember "uftwhatever" or count(self).

```
extension String {
    func length() -> Int {
        return count(self)
    }
}
```

But this means to call it I need to use something like...

```
let l = myString.length()
```

I'd my prefer to do...

```
let l = myString.length
```

But I can't figure it out. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. You just have to create it as a read-only computed property as follow:

> Read-Only Computed Properties
>
> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a
>   read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always
>   returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be
>   set to a different value.
>
> NOTE
>
> You must declare computed properties—including read-only computed
>   properties—as variable properties with the var keyword, because their
>   value is not fixed. The let keyword is only used for constant
>   properties, to indicate that their values cannot be changed once they
>   are set as part of instance initialization.
>
> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by
>   removing the get keyword and its braces:

```
extension String {
    var length: Int {
        return count(self)   // Swift 1.2
    }
}


"Hello World".length // 11
```

Comment: Very interesting! I never would have found this simply because of the naming, it's just not something I would have looked for. Thanks!

Comment: If there is no parameters I use a read-only computed property otherwise I use a function

Comment: I have to say, both the name and syntax for this feature are bizarre. I don't know about you, but when I see this I think "a function without parameters" not "read-only computed property". And in my mind I should be able to simply leave off the () on a function. Swift has some very odd syntax...

Comment: That's funny I love this way of doing it